# Identify changes to a table/variable

Tags: lua

I have several tables/variables (sampled below):

```
mytable = { ['100'] = { ['2']=0,['3']=0,['5']=0,['6']=0,['7']=0,['9']=0},
            ['101'] = { ['8']={['81']=0,['86']=0},
                        ['13']={['81']=0},
                        ['30']={['81']=0,['82']=0,['83']=0,['84']=0,['85']=0} },
            ['102'] = { ['81']={['location']='left',['3']=1} }
          }
mytable2 = 5
```

I need a function to pass a table/variable structured like one of the two above (could be either one) that will differentiate between current and previous data, and return a table/variable that only consists of the data that has changed since last called per client (a unique ID passed with the table/variable).  The tables can grow or change between execution of the function.

So if the following updates occurred between execution of the function:

```
mytable['101']['8']['81']=1
mytable['102']['81']['4']=0
```

the function would return

```
mytable = { ['101'] = { ['8']={['81']=1} },
            ['102'] = { ['81']={['4']=0} }
          }
```

Comment: Ummm, the second "structure" is not actually a table. How do you want to represent the "changes" in this scenario?

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question for clarity and added the example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this adds empty keys, I think it will work for me:

```
--t is the table and pt is the previous table

function deepchange(t,pt)
if (pt == nil) then return t, true end
if type(t) ~= 'table' then return t,t ~= pt end
local res = {}
local sd = false
for k,v in pairs(t) do
    if type(v) == 'table' then v = deepchange(v,pt[k]) end
    if pt[k] ~= v then 
        res[k] = v
        sd = true
    end
end
return res,sd
end
```

**UPDATED to handle second case and remove unnecessary lines related to get and set metatable...**

**UPDATED again to handle null previous tables.**

Answer (score 1):

There's a thing about tables you'll run into: tables are passed by reference (unless you do a deep copy). So if you do:

```
A={1,2,3}
B=A
B[1]=nil
--[[then]]
print(A[1]==nil)-- prints true.
```

Thus having a "new table" and an "old table" requires some extra effort from you.
Either you do a [deep copy](http://snippets.luacode.org/snippets/Deep_copy_of_a_Lua_Table_2) of the table to have something as reference (not place efficient).

Or you don't directly change the table itself, but use a proxy. This only does it for a single level of tables, but I think you could embed the structure in the proxy table, and have the values in the real ones:

```
mytable={}
do
    local changes={}
    mt={
    __index=function(t,k)
        if k=="reset" then
             return function()
                 changes={}
                 return true
             end
        elseif k=="getChanges" then
             return function() return changes end
        else
             return mytable[k]
        end
    end,
    __newindex=function(t,k,v)
        changes[k]=v
        mytable[k]=v
    end
    }
    prox=setmetatable({},mt)
end
prox[1]=1
prox[2]=2
for k,v in pairs(prox:getChanges()) do print(k,v) end
prox:reset()
for k,v in pairs(prox:getChanges()) do print(k,v) end
```

Implementing this recursively might be some of work. I guess you should ask yourself the question if it would not be simpler to write a simple function that keeps logs of transactions to your table.

Comment: I feared when I asked the question that the answers would be beyond my current understanding of Lua.  Unfortunately, I do not understand your answer.

Comment: Basically you use a dummy table in place which handles writes (the __newindex method) and reads (the __index method). You'll need to read some tutorials etc about metamethods to understand this. For extending it to nested structures you either have to have a more complex set of metamethods to keep the transactions, since each table is an object in its own right.