# lua - how to detect changes to variables in a lua script?

Tags: lua

I created a table to include key-value pairs of elements that I want to monitor and detect in case the values change. How can I detect that a value of a key has changed and do something in case it has changed?

I tried to follow the solution posted [lua - identify changes to a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071459/identify-changes-to-a-table-variable) but got only as far as the code below. Any suggestions on how to proceed would help.

```
-- create a table of values to be monitored
vt = {["key1"] = 0, ["key2"] = 1}
vt1 = {}
setmetatable(vt, vt1)
```

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/13.html

Comment: The trick is to implement `__newindex` to fetch changes, then store the value somewhere (but not in the same table because newindex only triggers if the key does not exist), and use `__index` to return the value (which is not at the given key because of previous remark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Luke has pointed out, the trick is to use an empty "proxy" table.

```lua
local t = {key1 = 0, key2 = 1}
local proxy = setmetatable({}, {
    __index = t,
    __newindex = function(_, key, value)
       local old_value = t[key]
       if value ~= old_value then
           print("key", key, "changed from", old_value, "to", value)
       end
       t[key] = value
    end,
    __pairs = function(_) return pairs(t) end,
    __len = function(_) return #t end,
})
proxy.key1 = 1 -- prints "key key1 changed from 0 to 1"
proxy.key1 = 1 -- does not print
```

A few notes:

- `__index`, `__pairs` and `__len` simply delegate to `t`. When the PiL was written, `__pairs` and `__len` didn't exist.
- The metatable *may not be set on `t`*, otherwise you *could not keep track of changes*
- There is no need to use `raw` methods since `t` doesn't have the metatable set. In fact it is probably preferable to not use `raw` methods in case `t` itself is just (another) proxy table.

Caveat: `rawget` and `rawset` can still be used to write straight to the proxy table, breaking this. Table identity will also be different since obviously `proxy ~= t`.